# Why debug print does not formatted an enum as expected?

Tags: rust

I need to print as debug a value from enum and format it. Then, I wrote this code like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyEnum {
    AB,
}

fn main() {
    let value = MyEnum::AB;
    println!("[{: <3?}]", value);
}
```

But, the result is `[AB]` while I expected that the result is `[AB ]`. Why? How to add paddings in a debug print?

Comment: See also https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55584

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the behavior implemented when deriving `Debug` for an `enum` as you can see with:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyEnum {
    AB(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let value = MyEnum::AB(42);
    println!("[{:<3?}]", value);
}
```

Output:

```
[AB(42 )]
```

I think you need to implement `Debug` yourself:

```
enum MyEnum {
    AB,
}

use std::fmt;

impl fmt::Debug for MyEnum {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            MyEnum::AB => f.pad("AB"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let value = MyEnum::AB;
    println!("[{:<3?}]", value);
}
```

Output:

```
[AB ]
```

Comment: In my case, is bad implementing `Debug` myself, because I have many cases at enum, I'll looking for another solution. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I just opened an issue at rust-lang: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55749

Comment: @Macabeus The easiest work-around is to use `println!("[{:<3}]", format!("{:?}", value))`.